# Detecting attached USB devices under Mac OSX

Tags: c, macos, usb

First of all a statement: I'm a newbie when it comes to programming for the Mac. However I have an assignment which requires USB communication with a device so I thought I'll start with something basic.

I took the code from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/USBPrivateDataSample/Introduction/Intro.html), built it and ran it from the Terminal. It starts up and writes:

> Looking for devices matching vendor ID=1351 and product ID=8193.
>
> Starting run loop.

However after this, if I plug in and out USB devices (I tried: iPod, GPS, mouse) nothing gets written on the screen, although as much as I understand there should be whenever I connect and disconnect a device.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can also use `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` on a terminal

Answer (score 10):

I found /Developer/Applications/Utilities/USB Prober to be of great use.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that this utility is not in recent versions of the developer tools.

Comment: There's some links to download it at http://touch-base.com/documentation/USBMacProber.htm