# Detect iOS device/simulator connected/running on a Mac, using shell or python?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, ipad, simulator

I am working on a tool for **jailbroken** iOS devices. This tool will be run on a Mac OS 10.8.

Here's what I would like to achieve:

- When I run the tool (preferably `sh` or `py` or some script) it should be able to detect if a Simulator is running, or
- if an iPhone/iPad is connected, and
- list all such devices (real/virtual).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to detect a connected iPhone, [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3820288/119114).  Something like this:

```sh
$ system_profiler SPUSBDataType | grep iPhone
```

will detect whether an iPhone is connected or not (you probably need a different grep for iPads).

The full(er) output of that command, without the `| grep iPhone` is:

```sh
        iPhone:

          Product ID: 0x12a8
          Vendor ID: 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.)
          Version: 5.10
          Serial Number: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
          Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
          Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
          Location ID: 0xfa120000 / 5
          Current Available (mA): 500
          Current Required (mA): 500
          Extra Operating Current (mA): 500
```

So, depending on what you want your script's output to look like, you may need to use your favorite scripting language to parse the above content.

To detect the simulator, try something like this (†):

```sh
$ ps -A | grep "iPhone Simulator "
```

which yields:

> 501 12115   135   0  1:53AM ??         0:06.12 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone Simulator -SessionOnLaunch NO

Without specific guidance on how the output should look, it's hard to give you more.  As with any scripting task, you should write it in the language you're good at.

Hopefully, that's a start.  Maybe others can build on this, or suggest alternatives.

### Update

† On newer SDK versions, you must grep for the simulator with

```sh
$ ps -A | grep "iOS Simulator"
```